# Why ShuffleConsumerPlugin doesn't start before mapping?

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

I created a custom implementation of `ShuffleConsumerPlugin` and it works. However, it is instantiated after my mapping task is done:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1582630093_0001_m_000000_0
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > sort
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1582630093_0001_m_000000_0' done.
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for reduce tasks
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1582630093_0001_r_000000_0
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Using ShuffleConsumerPlugin: FooPlugin
```

Reduce task starts after the mapping one is finished. I'm setting `mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps` to `0.0` for the job as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672676/when-do-reduce-tasks-start-in-hadoop), but it doesn't make any difference.

I'm using Hadoop 2.5.1

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you are working in local mode. So there will be only one mapper run. Reduce phase will start when AT least one mapper delivers his output entirely (with mentioned setting mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps =  0.0).