# PIG script: reducer preempted to make room for pending map attempts

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I run multiples instances of the same PIG script with different parameters.

When the cluster is under heavy load, Map Reduce jobs logs show lots of reducers preempted, which takes times:

```
Reducer preempted to make room for pending map attempts Container killed 
by the ApplicationMaster. Container killed on request. Exit code is 143 
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

How to avoid such preemptions issue to minimize script execution time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672676/when-do-reduce-tasks-start-in-hadoop) link.

In short, you can use one of below commands

```
SET mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps 1.00;
SET mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps 1.00;
```

depending on your Hadoop version (latter on is for Hadoop 2.4.1+). It will start reducers once all mappers art done.