# Flow of execution in Map Reduce

Tags: mapreduce

I knew that the reducer cannot start until the Mapper is run fully. I want to know if the reduce in the Reducer can run while the Shuffle or Sort is still running /not fully completed.

Comment: It seems your question is completely answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11673808/2700344

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do reduce tasks start in Hadoop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672676/when-do-reduce-tasks-start-in-hadoop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reducer can start even if "mapper task have partially completed". The param controlling it is mapreduce.slowstart

Follow this.
http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/understanding-map-reduce-the-missing-guide/

Comment: But in most of the blogs, including one mentioned by @leftjoin indicate that map tasks must be complete before the reduce task starts.