# how to access Mapper Counter value in a Reducer?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to acces the myCounter.my value in reducer :

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable>
{
    public static enum myCounter{my};

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
    {
        context.getCounter(myCounter.my).increment(1);
        context.write( new ImmutableBytesWritable ( ),new ImmutableBytesWritable() );
    }
}


public static class Reduce extends Reducer<ImmutableBytesWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable, Text, Text>
{
    @Override
    public void reduce(ImmutableBytesWritable key,Iterable<ImmutableBytesWritable> result,Context context)
    {

    }
}
```

[Accessing a mapper's counter from a reducer(for old API is given )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450290/accessing-a-mappers-counter-from-a-reducer?rq=1)
how to make it work for new API ?

**Or**

I want to know the total number of mapper output ? Is there any better way ? (i am not able to access counter in Reducer:

`Group Name->org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter  Counter Name->MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS`)

Thanks

Comment: which hadoop version are you using?

Comment: [example](http://lintool.github.com/Cloud9/docs/content/counters.html)

Comment: @faizan: ty 
but as you can see the exanple is abt accessing counter via Job ,,either in main(String args[]) or other functions only after the Job has finished ruining ,**where as I want to access it in Reduce**.
so still my question is not solved .

Answer (score 2):

You to make it work for new API by accessing the counters via job object.

```
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
Cluster cluster = new Cluster(conf);
Job currentJob = cluster.getJob(context.getJobID());
long val=currentJob.getCounters().findCounter(myCounter.my).getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your counter value in reducer using the same code

```
Counter counter = context.getCounter( myCounter.my );
        counter.getValue();
```

[also see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450290/accessing-a-mappers-counter-from-a-reducer)

Comment: Its Not working .counter.getValue will give zero since ,the context(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context<ImmutableBytesWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable, Text, Text>
) in Reducer is different then context(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context<ImmutableBytesWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable, Text, Text>
) of Mapper .

Comment: as far as i know the context gives you access to same Global counter.

Comment: so it does not affect whether you are accessing context from setup or map or reduce method [link](http://diveintodata.org/2011/03/15/an-example-of-hadoop-mapreduce-counter/)

Comment: At first even ,i tried that but its not working , its returning zero , so i came to that conclusion .

Comment: I think you will get your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450290/accessing-a-mappers-counter-from-a-reducer)

Comment: I have shared this link in my qus . Its old API i am using new API . 
**How to implement that solution in new API ?**

Answer (score -2):

You can access as follows:

```
Map.myCounter.my // static fields you can access by it's class name.
```

Comment: In hadoop Map-Reduce framework it doesn't  work like this .My Question is specific for Map_reduce Framework .