# Old API to New API

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

[My Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577128/how-to-access-mapper-counter-value-in-a-reducer/12579138#comment16954278_12579138)

since only feasible ans to that question is found in  [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450290/accessing-a-mappers-counter-from-a-reducer?rq=1) 
And the answer is in old API . So that force me to put **a stupid question** of translating these line to **New API** :

```
private long mapperCounter;

     @Override
     public void configure(JobConf conf) {
               JobClient client = new JobClient(conf);
               RunningJob parentJob = 
               client.getJob(JobID.forName( conf.get("mapred.job.id") ));
               mapperCounter = parentJob.getCounters().getCounter(MAP_COUNTER_NAME);
      }
```

Note : I want this code in reducer so inherited  functions available are :

```
            @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {


    }



    @Override
    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {

    }



    @Override
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        Job job=new Job(context.getConfiguration());


    }



    @Override
    public void reduce(ImmutableBytesWritable key,Iterable<ImmutableBytesWritable> result,Context context )
    {

    }
```

Thanks :)  :)

Comment: +1 and added as a favorite for the old API snippet!

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.slideshare.net/sh1mmer/upgrading-to-the-new-map-reduce-api) presentation summarizes the changes between the old and new API.

Comment: +1 for a great link to a nice overview, but golly I wish it were just text... I can't find such a concise reference anywhere else. Anyone?