# Get number of input records in Hadoop reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In my reducer, I require the total number of "lines" of input that were processed by the mappers.

sample input:

- line,1,of,input
- line,2,of,input
- line,3,of,input

So, in all of the Reducers, I need to have access to the whatever was emitted by the Mappers **plus** the total number of lines (in this case 3).

I'm assuming that I will need either multiple jobs or chain together some mappers and/or reducers but I'm unsure of the proper way.

Note: This is not a simple average program, so I can't just have a single key from the mapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a counter: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters.html

Hadoop predefines a set of standard counters (included the number of processed line by the mappers, which is maybe what you're looking for), but you can also define your own custom counter. Here's a sample of how to do it: [Accessing a mapper's counter from a reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450290/accessing-a-mappers-counter-from-a-reducer)

Answer (score 4):

`job.getCounters().findCounter(TaskCounter.MAP_INPUT_RECORDS).getValue()` to get the total numbers of records.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have not specified a custom Record Reader, you just need to get the value of the counter `MAP_INPUT_RECORDS` in the `setup` or `configure` method of your reducer (based on whether you use the new, or the old API, respectively).

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450290/accessing-a-mappers-counter-from-a-reducer) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609028/is-there-a-list-of-all-standard-not-custom-hadoop-mapreduce-counters), for instructions on both APIs.