# Access the Counter in the setup of reducer in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to get the number of input records lines in mapper by running

```
job.getCounters().findCounter(TaskCounter.MAP_INPUT_RECORDS).getValue()
```

Actually, it works after the job is completed and I want to do the same thing in the setup phase of the reducer. I have tried to overwrite 2 setup functions according to this page [Accessing a mapper's counter from a reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450290/accessing-a-mappers-counter-from-a-reducer). However, neither of them work and both of them return null pointer exception.

```
    @Override
    protected void setup(Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, DoubleWritable>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        Cluster cluster = new Cluster(conf);
        //RunningJob job = (RunningJob) cluster.getJob(context.getJobID());
        Job job = cluster.getJob(context.getJobID());
        System.out.println(job.getCounters().findCounter(TaskCounter.MAP_INPUT_RECORDS).getValue());
    }

    @Override
    protected void setup(Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, DoubleWritable>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        JobClient client = new JobClient(conf);
        RunningJob job = client.getJob(JobID.forName(conf.get("mapred.map.id")));
        //Job job = (Job) client.getJob((JobID) context.getJobID());
        System.out.println(job.getCounters().findCounter(TaskCounter.MAP_INPUT_RECORDS).getValue());

    }
```

Can anyone help me fix the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The reducer would get a subsection of the data read by the entire map-phase (one key per reducer) so why would you need this?

Comment: Actually, this is for a TFIDF calculation job. The  MAP_INPUT_RECORDS is the number of docs in the entire collection. I want to get that number so that I can do my calculation in my reducer. :)

Comment: So, is the error from `job.getCounters()` being null? As far as I know, `cluster.getJob(context.getJobID())` should return you the right information

Comment: Yes, cluster.getJob(context.getJobID()) works and the error is from job.getCounters(....).

Comment: Can you print the counters object or loop over what data *is* within it?

Comment: Well if I do   Counters counters = job.getCounters()   , here is where NullPointerException comes from. So I got nothing in counters. And I try to use RunningJob Class to declare the job, it does not work either.

Comment: `conf.get("mapred.map.id")` shouldn't work. That property is deprecated... Getting the job ID from the context is correct, though, if you look at the JavaDoc, it says getting the counters,  *May return null if the job has been retired and the job is no longer in the completed job store*